# Reformat string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use `Regex.Replace()` to change all the patterns like (number)(letter) into (number)(space)(letter).

E.g.
15A >>> 15 A
123KK >>> 123 KK

Comment: I tried "([ ]{1,}[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+[ ]{1,})" (including spaces at the start and at the end) but I don't know if it's possible to replace it using something variables-like in my regular expression.

Comment: @Nickon and _that_ is the problem you should ask, not just what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this expression `(\d+)(.+)` and this replacement: `$1 $2`.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("15A","(\\d+)(.*)","$1 $2"));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this code

```
newValue = Regex.Replace(value, "([0-9])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex r =new Regex(@"(?<=[0-9]{1,})(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,})");
r.Replace("t6y8sss5"," ");
```